# How to loop over column values to drop columns which are constant in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

df:

```
Id   ColA   ColB    Colc
1    1       2       3
1    1       5       3
1    1       7       2
2    3       4       5  
2    6       4       5
2    3       4       5
3    1       9       7
3    1       7       9
3    9       9       7
```

i need to drop those columns where values are constant based on Id.
Suppose for id 1 ColA has constant values so drop for Id 1.

Output:

```
Id    Column_Names
1     ColB
1     ColC
2     ColA
3     ColA
3     ColB
3     ColC
```

Comment: it has value 1 for id 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets us try with `groupby` + `nunique`:

```
m = df.groupby('Id').nunique().ne(1).stack()
out = pd.DataFrame(list(m.index[m]), columns=['Id', 'column_names'])
```

**Details:**

Group the dataframe on `Id` and aggregate the columns `A`, `B` and `C` using `nunique` to count the number of unique occurrence, then compare the unique occurences with with `1` to create a boolean mask, followed by stack to reshape:

```
>>> m

Id      
1   ColA    False
    ColB     True
    Colc     True
2   ColA     True
    ColB    False
    Colc    False
3   ColA     True
    ColB     True
    Colc     True
dtype: bool
```

Then filter the multiindex values which satisfy the condition of uniqueness i.e. where the unique occurrences are not equal to 1:

```
>>> m.index[m]

MultiIndex([(1, 'ColB'),
            (1, 'Colc'),
            (2, 'ColA'),
            (3, 'ColA'),
            (3, 'ColB'),
            (3, 'Colc')],
           names=['Id', None])
```

Finally create a new dataframe from the above multiindex values with columns `Id` and `column_names`

```
>>> out
   Id column_names
0   1         ColB
1   1         Colc
2   2         ColA
3   3         ColA
4   3         ColB
5   3         Colc
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), filter then convert index to DataFrame by  and [`MultiIndex.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html):

```
s = df.groupby('Id').nunique().stack().ne(1)
df = s.index[s].to_frame(index=False).rename(columns={1:'column_names'})
print (df)
   Id column_names
0   1         ColB
1   1         Colc
2   2         ColA
3   3         ColA
4   3         ColB
5   3         Colc
```